# Django, How to avoid 'matching query does not exist'

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
try:
    testmodel2 = TestModel_2.objects.get(description='a')
except TestModel_2.DoesNotExist:
    testmodel2 = None
```

**models.py**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TestModel_2(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "TestModel %s" % self.description
```

**Question:**
Why though I set `DoesNotExist`, `myapp.models.DoesNotExist: TestModel_2 matching query does not exist.` is occurred?

**EDIT**

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/test2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonDev\interpreters\interpreter1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 170, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'TestModelLog_2' object has no attribute '_test_foreignkey_2_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonDev\interpreters\interpreter1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\pythonDev\interpreters\interpreter1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\pythonDev\interpreters\interpreter1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\pythonDev\project\logintest\renoauth\views.py", line 56, in test2
    if testmodel_2_log.test_foreignkey_2 is None:
  File "D:\pythonDev\interpreters\interpreter1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 179, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "D:\pythonDev\interpreters\interpreter1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 385, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
renoauth.models.DoesNotExist: TestModel_2 matching query does not exist.
[06/Jan/2018 16:20:24] "POST /accounts/test2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15678
```

**related model**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TestModelLog_2(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    test_foreignkey = models.ForeignKey(TestModel_2, related_name='test_foreignkey_1', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    test_foreignkey_2 = models.ForeignKey(TestModel_2, related_name='test_foreignkey_2', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: because the error in the except is not correct, try keeping only except and check once

Comment: @Exprator sorry for more question, How to make it error except correct? Would you give me more explanation?

Comment: Can you please add the full stacktrace?

Comment: @dahrens I added some edits

Comment: `AttributeError: 'TestModelLog_2' object has no attribute '_test_foreignkey_2_cache'` Do you have relations on another model to this one?

Comment: Did you ran `python manage.py makemigration` and `python manage.py migrate` after creating `TestModelLog_2`?

Comment: The error is telling you the does not exist exception is occurring on the line `if testmodel_2_log.test_foreignkey_2 is None:`, which you haven’t shown. It’s not clear why that view is running during the exception handling. It would be clearer if you showed the complete view that is handling `/accounts/test2/`, and your middleware settings.

Comment: Please use the real model names instead of made up names like `TestModelLog_2`, it will make the question clearer.

Comment: As your comments, while trying to resolve this problem, I found it there was migration problem. Because I delete all migration files and re-try it, it works fine. Thanks for all your comments. Even I really do not know why this was happened, It is solved now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query = TestModel_2.objects.filter(description='a')

if not query.exists():
    return None
return query
```

Comment: would recommend to save the result of the `filter` and then after the exists check just `get()` it. So, when don't need to write the query twice

Comment: Filter is better option because you can get more then one result, and if you get 2 results you will have error.

Comment: your secound statement already uses a get(), but it has the query again, instead of just using the query from the last statement (through a variable)

Comment: here you go with your answer